# Problem when updating using Software Update

Tags: macos, software-update

I tried to update Mac OS X using Software Update. But when I tap on software updates, it's checking software updates and listing the available updates.

I didn't see Mac OS X update available in the list. I am not able to do this. Can you guys please help ?

Answer (score 1):

What is your current OS X version ??

The latest OS X is 10.6.7 - and if you can't get it through "Software Update", then you can download the whole OS X v10.6.7 Update Combo here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1361

Answer (score 1):

You may already be on the latest version (check with the menu item **** > **About This Mac**).
If not, you may have accidentally “Ignored” the update (⌫ in *Software Update* or the menu item **Update** > **Ignore Update…**).

You might try the *Software Update* menu item **Software Update** > **Reset Ignored Updates** (it is only enabled if you have Ignored an update in the past).